# ASP.Net MVC3 RawUrl check

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have this JavaScript code to modify the class of menu items:

```
switch(@Request.RawUrl.Trim()) 
{
    case "/MyInfo":
    case "/":
    case "/MyDocuments":
        // add the javascript here
        break;
}
```

My MyDocuments Urls will always be suffixed with `?Page=x` where x is the page number of the documents list.

How would I modify the code in the switch statement to make the modified URLs included in the menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
switch (Request.Url.AbsolutePath.ToLower())
{
    case "/myinfo":
    case "/":
    case "/mydocuments":
        // add the javascript here
        break;
}
```

Comment: Would that capture /MyDocuments?page=2